# Does PostgreSQL's VALIDATE CONSTRAINT check rows that were already checked?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

[PostgreSQL's documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) makes it clear that a constraint added as `NOT VALID` will still get checked for rows that are subsequently updated or inserted.

I have a table with quite high "churn". That is, I know that in two weeks, most of the unchecked rows that currently exist will have been deleted. And lots of new rows (which will have been checked) will exist.

So my question is: if I delay running the `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` until 2 weeks from now, will PostgreSQL still need to check all the rows that get inserted between now and then? Or is it intelligent enough to know which rows have already been checked, therefore reducing the time needed for an exclusive lock while running `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT`?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer with a test. I wrote the following script with Ruby and Active Record:

```
require "active_record"
require "logger"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "postgresql", database: "test")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new($stderr)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :befores, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :other_id
  end

  create_table :afters, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :other_id
  end

  create_table :others, force: true
end

conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

conn.execute(
  "ALTER TABLE befores " \
  "ADD CONSTRAINT befores_others_fk " \
  "FOREIGN KEY (other_id) " \
  "REFERENCES others (id) " \
  "NOT VALID"
)

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil

N = (ENV["N"] || 1_000_000).to_i

print "Inserting #{N} rows..."
N.times do |i|
  conn.execute("INSERT INTO others (id) VALUES (#{i})")
  conn.execute("INSERT INTO befores (id, other_id) VALUES (#{i}, #{i})")
  conn.execute("INSERT INTO afters (id, other_id) VALUES (#{i}, #{i})")
end
puts "done"

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new($stderr)

conn.execute(
  "ALTER TABLE afters " \
  "ADD CONSTRAINT afters_others_fk " \
  "FOREIGN KEY (other_id) " \
  "REFERENCES others (id) " \
  "NOT VALID"
)

conn.execute "ALTER TABLE befores VALIDATE CONSTRAINT befores_others_fk"
conn.execute "ALTER TABLE afters VALIDATE CONSTRAINT afters_others_fk"
```

I then ran it with 100k rows:

```
$ N=100000 ruby test.rb 
-- create_table(:befores, {:force=>true})
D, [2014-04-23T23:00:41.925325 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (6.3ms)  DROP TABLE "befores"
D, [2014-04-23T23:00:41.935557 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (9.6ms)  CREATE TABLE "befores" ("id" serial primary key, "other_id" integer) 
   -> 0.0322s
-- create_table(:afters, {:force=>true})
D, [2014-04-23T23:00:41.940595 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (3.3ms)  DROP TABLE "afters"
D, [2014-04-23T23:00:41.948406 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (7.5ms)  CREATE TABLE "afters" ("id" serial primary key, "other_id" integer) 
   -> 0.0127s
-- create_table(:others, {:force=>true})
D, [2014-04-23T23:00:41.952883 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (3.0ms)  DROP TABLE "others"
D, [2014-04-23T23:00:41.960750 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (7.5ms)  CREATE TABLE "others" ("id" serial primary key) 
   -> 0.0122s
D, [2014-04-23T23:00:41.963809 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (2.7ms)  ALTER TABLE befores ADD CONSTRAINT befores_others_fk FOREIGN KEY (other_id) REFERENCES others (id) NOT VALID
Inserting 100000 rows...done
D, [2014-04-23T23:11:37.105878 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (3.3ms)  ALTER TABLE afters ADD CONSTRAINT afters_others_fk FOREIGN KEY (other_id) REFERENCES others (id) NOT VALID
D, [2014-04-23T23:11:37.196819 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (90.7ms)  ALTER TABLE befores VALIDATE CONSTRAINT befores_others_fk
D, [2014-04-23T23:11:37.287966 #6411] DEBUG -- :    (91.0ms)  ALTER TABLE afters VALIDATE CONSTRAINT afters_others_fk
```

Since there is no real difference between the last two statements, my conclusion is that all rows do indeed get rechecked when running `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT`. The postgres version used to test is 9.2.6.